# round dashed border bug

Tags: css, border

I am trying implement something like that[image]

All is ok, but I can see weird bug

[image]

How to make it without doubled dashes here?

Left side code is div with nex parameters:

```
position: relative;
width: 156px;
height: 192px;
right: 50px;
bottom: 113px;
border-width: 2px;
border-radius: 92px;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
border-right-color: transparent;
border-color: #c7cac7;
border-style: dashed;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't responsive, an idea could be to add a pipe "|" with the same color as the background via `:before` or `:after` pseudo-class and align it where you expected a break in the line.

```
:before {
content: "|";
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 100px;
color: #CCC;}
```